# Hide Some Element With Local Storage In React

Tags: reactjs

I want to hide some navigation when the user haven't login yet, so I use local storage to save user's id and use if logic to hide and show the navigation, but when i clear the data in local storage and compare it to null, the navigation still showed up.

Here is the code to save data in local storage

```
loginUser = () => {
    Axios.post('http://private-6fdd31-intern1.apiary-mock.com/interns/login', this.state.user)
        .then((res) => {
            if(res.data.role === "admin")
            {
                localStorage.setItem("user", res.data.user_id)
                this.props.history.push('/member-list');
            }
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
}
```

This is how I compare and clear the data when logout navigation is clicked

```
handleLogout = () => {
    localStorage.clear("user");
}

render() {
    return(
        <Router>
            <Fragment>
                <div className="navigation">
                    { localStorage.getItem("user") !== null?
                        <Fragment>
                            <Link to="/member-list">Member</Link>
                            <Link to="/override-list">Override</Link>
                            <Link onClick={this.handleLogout} to="/">Logout</Link>
                        </Fragment>
                        : null
                    }
                </div>
                <Route path="/" exact component={routeProps => <Login {...routeProps}/>}/>
                <Route path="/member-list" component={MemberDashboard}/>             
                <Route path="/override-list" component={OverrideDashboard}/>
            </Fragment>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

Comment: I think you have to `forceUpdate` after doing `localStorage.clear("user");`. The component is not re-rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react native wont call `render()` method as long as there is no state or props update, you need to call `this.forceUpdate()` to force a rerender. Documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html like

```
handleLogout = () => {
    localStorage.clear("user");
    this.forceUpdate()
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your response, have some other issue, when it moves to other component (in my case MemberDashboard), I need to reload it before the navigation show up. I put `this.forceUpdate()` on its `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the state to save the user when you set to local storage and same thing when you handleLogout?

```
if(res.data.role === "admin")
{
 this.setState({ user: res.data.user_id})
 localStorage.setItem("user", res.data.user_id)
 this.props.history.push('/member-list');
}

handleLogout = () => {
 localStorage.clear("user");
 this.setState({ user: ""})
}
```

So when state is updated, the component re-renders.

Comment: already tried this. If using state, when you click refresh button, all the state will return to its initial value